# jquery ajax still sending url in url bar while using $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to send message with php. But I'm still getting GET request in url bar instead POST. The url is always display in the address bar.

Here is my form, jquery and php code

html form :

```
                <form class="form-horizontal contactez">
                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>Laissez-nous un message</legend>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nom_m"></label>  
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input id="nom_m" name="nom_m" type="text" placeholder="Nom" class="form-control input-md" class="nom_m">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email_m"></label>  
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input id="email_m" name="email_m" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" class="email_m">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="objet"></label>  
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input id="objet" name="objet" type="text" placeholder="Sujet" class="form-control input-md" class="objet">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Textarea -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="message"></label>
                      <div class="col-md-4">                     
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" class="message">Message</textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-indigo submitBtn" type="submit"> Message <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

jquery code:
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('.contactez').submit(function(){

        var nom_m = $('#nom_m').val();
        var email_m = $('#email_m').val();
        var message_m = $('#message').val();
        var objet_m = $('#objet');
        var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

        if(nom_m.trim()==''){

            $('#nom_m').focus() ;
            return false ;

        } 
        else if(email_m.trim()=='')
        {
            $('#email_m').focus() ;
            return false ;
        }
        else if(objet_m.trim()=='')
        {
            $('#objet').focus() ;
            return false ;
        }
        else if(message_m.trim()=='')
        {
            $('#message').focus() ;
            return false ;
        }
        else if(email_m.trim()!='' && !reg.test(email_m))
        {
            bootbox.alert('Entrer une adresse mail valide');
            $('#email_m').focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {

            $.post("submit_message.php",{nom:nom_m,email:email_m,objet:objet_m,message:message_m},function(data){
                bootbox.alert('Message envoyé');

            }); 
        }
        return false ;
    });

});
```

php code :

```
<?php 
    require "install.php" ;

    $nom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nom']) ;
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) ;
    $objet = htmlspecialchars($_POST['objet']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

    if(isset($connection) && !empty($nom) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)){

        $to = "name@gmail.com";
        //$subject = $objet ;
        $headers = "From : ". $email ."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\n\r\n";

        mail($to,$objet,$message,$headers); 
    }

 ?>
```

I use $.post but when I inspect code with browser I see Request Method: GET. And the php file is not load.

Help me.

Comment: Can you [edit] in the `<form>` into the question? I suspect the error is that the JS you've written isn't connected to the form you think it is

Comment: @HPierce it's done. I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your handler isn't returning `false` because you have an error in one of your assignments:

```
var objet_m = $('#objet');
```

An then the line `else if(objet_m.trim()=='')` causes the following error:

```
TypeError: objet_m.trim is not a function
```

If you want to ensure the form isn't submitted, use `preventDefault()`, that also enables you to remove all those `return false` from your function.

```
$('.contactez').submit(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var nom_m = $('#nom_m').val();
  var email_m = $('#email_m').val();
  var message_m = $('#message').val();
  var objet_m = $('#objet').val();
  var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  // Rest of the function ommited
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the steps I took to debug this:

First, prevent the default event handler of the form submission explicitly. This is done to hopefully catch any bugs that arise before the function hits a `return false;`.

```
$('.contactez').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... 
}
```

Now when you run the code, you'll get this error

[image]

Your script is crashing before it gets a chance to `return false` and block the form submission, so your browser is using the default behavior when a form is submitted by redirecting (which is what you're seeing when you say the address bar is changing).

You probably just need to add `.val()` to this line `var objet_m = $('#objet')`.

```
$('.contactez').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var nom_m = $('#nom_m').val();
    var email_m = $('#email_m').val();
    var message_m = $('#message').val();
    var objet_m = $('#objet').val();
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

    // ...
}
```

I'm getting another error on the page related to `bootbox` not being defined, but I suspect that's just a dependcy you haven't discussed here. Hopefully the `e.preventDefault()` step gives you enough tools to continue debugging.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks It's working. It's was the .val() I've forgot

Answer (score -1):

Low rep to add as a comment.

Have a look at your .htaccess file. (Don't have php stuff set up to check it and point you where to look at at the moment).
A few problems I remember that can happen are that the .htaccess file can overwrite you url and remove the .php extension - so you can either try searching the file and changing it or just try changing your url to `$.post("submit_message",....`
Another case was that a slash `/` would appear in the url causing the problems. 
Basically the problem revolves around that some settings cause your request to be redirected turning it to GET.